# Сохранение данных на стороне клиента

Tags: php

Попытаюсь подробно описать проблему. Разрабатываю сайт образовательного характера. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы та информация, которую обучающийся напишет в поля для ввода ответа, сохранялась где-либо (вопрос в том, где???) до того момента, пока он не отправит ответы в БД. Чтобы если он случайно закрыл страницу и захотел вернуться на неё, в полях для ввода ответов по умолчанию уже находилась введённая им до этого информация.
Примерный объём информации - 100кб.
Как это можно сделать (желательно, не используя БД)?

Comment: `localStorage` в помощь

Comment: [WebStorage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage) или [IndexedDB](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IndexedDB)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно использовать [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Пример использования:

```
<script>
     let data = [];

     # вы можете описать тут addEventListener, который получит информацию с полей input/textarea или других.
     $("input").each(function (i, input) {
         data.push(input.value);
     });

     localStorage.setItem('saved_data', data);
</script>
```

После этого вы сможете получить данные даже после обновления страницы:

```
<script>
    let data = localStorage.getItem('saved_data');
</script>
```